# Permisos en moodle desde PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cmd, moodle

Buenos días.

Antes que nada me gustaría aclarar que realmente no sé mucho de estos temas. Instalé **XAMPP** en Windows y estoy instalando **Moodle**. En Moodle me salen los siguientes errores:

***mysql_full_unicode_support#File_format***

> "Your database has tables using Antelope as the file format. Full UTF-8 support in MySQL and MariaDB requires the Barracuda file format. Please convert the tables to the Barracuda file format. See the documentation Administration via command line for details of a tool for converting InnoDB tables to Barracuda."

y

***mysql_full_unicode_support#Large_prefix***

> "For full support of UTF-8 both MySQL and MariaDB require you to change your MySQL setting 'innodb_large_prefix' to 'ON'. See the documentation for further details."

Siguiendo las intrucciones de moodle referidas en [este link](https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Administration_via_command_line#Tool_for_converting_tables), abro la consola con la opción de "Ejecutar como administrador" pero no me acepta la instruccion dada. La instrucción la tengo así:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/moodle/admin/cli>php /mysql_compressed_rows.php -l
```

Y me devuelve

> Could not open input file: mysql_compressed_rows.php

Por otro lado lo intenté con MySql iniciando con `mysql -u root` y con la instruccion `SET GLOBAL`. Al principio me funcionó, pero al reiniciar XAMPP no conserva los cambios hechos.

[image: MySQL SET GLOBAL]

Me dicen que puede ser una cuestión de permisos pero no sé como ni donde gestionarlos. Además con el mysql no entiendo por qué resetea los cambios hechos al momento de reiniciar XAMPP. Agradezco de veras muchísimo la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: saludos alguien por casualidad sabe como arreglar este problema en un hosting compartido? como dreamhost para configurar bien este problema y poder instalar moodle 3.4 graciass

Comment: @Faiberts Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/72155)

Answer (score 1):

Por si acaso a alguien le sirve. No supe ni pude resolver la cuestión de los permisos, pero los errores que describí los solucioné haciendo el procedimiento de `SET GLOBAL` descrito anteriormente y no reiniciando el `XAMPP`.